# Same name for inner class and property

Tags: c#, properties, naming-conventions, inner-classes

[Framework naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members) say "CONSIDER giving a property the same name as its type."  However, it seems that this cannot be done with inner classes, as this code does not compile:

```
class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public string C { get; set; }
    }
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any special syntax for these cases?

Comment: What is the question here? You can't do that with inner types, there is already something named "B". Its the same as if you had 2 properties with the same name...

Comment: Added question.

Comment: `CONSIDER` means 'try if it makes sense and is possible'. It isn't possible here (without changing the class to not be inner) so you can't do it.

Comment: `Is there any special syntax for these cases?` No.

Comment: @RonBeyer, the question which raises here: "What would be a naming convention here which makes sense, and more or less consistent with other naming conventions?" I mean if there is a type named: `Foo` then all naming conventions dictates, that a property which is a type of Foo should be declared as `Foo Foo {get; set;}`.  Now what...? Should we call the inner class as `FooClass`?  or should we call the property `Foo FooProperty {get; set;}`?

Comment: @g.pickardou I think you should ask that question on [Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) but I think the answer will boil down to "don't use inner classes that need to be exposed externally". If that's the case, make it a separate class. Only use inner classes for something that needs to be used internally in the class. Inner classes make it difficult to define interfaces (chicken and egg problem) or do things like injection.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Fair enough. I was just trying answer your question in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

After two years... but better later than never...

Credit goes to RonBeyer's comment to my comment.

**Don't use inner classes that need to be exposed externally**, then the problem will not even raise.